# Start editing a specific cell programmatically in GXT Grid

Tags: grid, gxt

I use a GXT Grid to show data in a table supporting inline editing.
Now I'd like to implement the possibility to move from the cell, which is in the editing state to the next by pressing the arrow keys.

To set a cell to the editing mode, I can use the method `GridInlineEditing.startEditing(GridCell)`. To get the cell, which is in the editing mode, I use `GridInlineEditing.getActiveCell()`.

What I'd like to know is how can I get the GridCell object of the cell next to the active cell? I can't find any method to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it if you know the column and row index.

grid.getView.getCell(row, col).focus();

FYI Tab will go to the next cell and Shift+Tab will go to the previous cell while editing in a grid.

Edit: To get the cell above the currently selected cell:

GridCell active = inlineEditor.getActiveCell();

GridCell cell = inlineEditor.getEditableGrid().walkCells(active.getRow()-1, active.getCol(), 1, callback);

You'll have to adapt their callback from the AbstractGrid, but that doesn't look too difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. focus() won't set the cell into edit mode and with getCell(), I only get the Element, but not a GridCell object. I know about the Tab, but with this, I'm not able to move up and down. Only to left and right.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Hopefully this will help you get the GridCell you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. But in my case, to select the cell above, I need to use _gridEdit.getEditableGrid().walkCells(cell.getRow() - 1, cell.getCol(), 1, callback);

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I'll edit the answer to match that.